# Detailed instructions for iPhone version of C&C - Red Alert?

Tags: ios, command-and-conquer-red-alert

I'm playing through the iPhone version of "Command And Conquer - Red Alert".

I've played older variants of C&C on other platforms so I know generally how RTS games work.  But what I cannot seem to figure out is some specific controls for some units - in particular, I'm on a level that asks me to use an engineer to blow up a bridge, but I have no idea how to use an engineer to do anything but capture enemy buildings (and that I had to figure out for myself).  Nor can I find the point of some buildings like a defense center.

Since the in-game guide is very basic and does not answer these questions, I was hoping there was an on-line manual somewhere that described what is going on in more detail - either from EA or someone else.  Are there sites I can visit for a real manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question about how to blow up the bridge: Mark the engineer and point out the building neerest to the bridge as a target - that will blow up the bridge. Enjoy and sorry for my english

Comment: Your english is excellent and I thank you for the tip about the bridge.  In fact that is the most important thing I wish to know, just to figure out how to get past that point in the game!!